# Can't change the background color using TailwindCss and Flowbite and Other Problems

Tags: nestjs, tailwind-css, flowbite

I was trying to use a template for sidebar with navbar for my site that I got from flowbite, I think I installed everything sucessfully but I can't change the background color. Also, I don't think they're related, but I'm having a problem importing the flowbite.min.js

Here is my code:

**Input.css:**

```
@import "tailwindcss/base";

@import "tailwindcss/components";

@import "tailwindcss/utilities";`
```

**Tailwind.config.js:**

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: ["./public/Templates/*.ejs",
            "./node_modules/flowbite/**/*.js",
            "./views/*.ejs", 
  ],
  theme: {
    colors: {
      roxo: '#8658E4'
    },
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [
    require('flowbite/plugin')
  ],
}
```

**sidenavber.ejs:**

```
<nav class="fixed top-0 z-50 w-full bg-roxo border-b border-gray-200 dark:bg-gray-800 dark:border-gray-700">
   <div class="px-3 py-3 lg:px-5 lg:pl-3">
     <div class="flex items-center justify-between">
       <div class="flex items-center justify-start">
         <button data-drawer-target="logo-sidebar" data-drawer-toggle="logo-sidebar" aria-controls="logo-sidebar" type="button" class="inline-flex items-center p-2 text-sm text-gray-500 rounded-lg sm:hidden hover:bg-gray-100 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-gray-200 dark:text-gray-400 dark:hover:bg-gray-700 dark:focus:ring-gray-600">
             <span class="sr-only">Open sidebar</span>
             <svg class="w-6 h-6" aria-hidden="true" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 20 20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                <path clip-rule="evenodd" fill-rule="evenodd" d="M2 4.75A.75.75 0 012.75 4h14.5a.75.75 0 010 1.5H2.75A.75.75 0 012 4.75zm0 10.5a.75.75 0 01.75-.75h7.5a.75.75 0 010 1.5h-7.5a.75.75 0 01-.75-.75zM2 10a.75.75 0 01.75-.75h14.5a.75.75 0 010 1.5H2.75A.75.75 0 012 10z"></path>
             </svg>
          </button>
         <a href="https://flowbite.com" class="flex ml-2 md:mr-24">
           <img src="https://flowbite.com/docs/images/logo.svg" class="h-8 mr-3" alt="FlowBite Logo" />
           <span class="self-center text-xl font-semibold sm:text-2xl whitespace-nowrap dark:text-white">Flowbite</span>
         </a>
       </div>
       <div class="flex items-center">
           <div class="flex items-center ml-3">
             <div>
               <button type="button" class="flex text-sm bg-gray-800 rounded-full focus:ring-4 focus:ring-gray-300 dark:focus:ring-gray-600" aria-expanded="false" data-dropdown-toggle="dropdown-user">
                 <span class="sr-only">Open user menu</span>
                 <img class="w-8 h-8 rounded-full" src="https://flowbite.com/docs/images/people/profile-picture-5.jpg" alt="user photo">
               </button>
             </div>
             <div class="z-50 hidden my-4 text-base list-none bg-white divide-y divide-gray-100 rounded shadow dark:bg-gray-700 dark:divide-gray-600" id="dropdown-user">
               <div class="px-4 py-3" role="none">
                 <p class="text-sm text-gray-900 dark:text-white" role="none">
                   Neil Sims
                 </p>
                 <p class="text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 truncate dark:text-gray-300" role="none">
                   neil.sims@flowbite.com
                 </p>
               </div>
               <ul class="py-1" role="none">
                 <li>
                   <a href="#" class="block px-4 py-2 text-sm text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-100 dark:text-gray-300 dark:hover:bg-gray-600 dark:hover:text-white" role="menuitem">Dashboard</a>
                 </li>
                 <li>
                   <a href="#" class="block px-4 py-2 text-sm text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-100 dark:text-gray-300 dark:hover:bg-gray-600 dark:hover:text-white" role="menuitem">Settings</a>
                 </li>
                 <li>
                   <a href="#" class="block px-4 py-2 text-sm text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-100 dark:text-gray-300 dark:hover:bg-gray-600 dark:hover:text-white" role="menuitem">Earnings</a>
                 </li>
                 <li>
                   <a href="#" class="block px-4 py-2 text-sm text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-100 dark:text-gray-300 dark:hover:bg-gray-600 dark:hover:text-white" role="menuitem">Sign out</a>
                 </li>
               </ul>
             </div>
           </div>
         </div>
     </div>
   </div>
 </nav>
 
 <aside id="logo-sidebar" class="fixed top-0 left-0 z-40 w-64 h-screen pt-20 transition-transform -translate-x-full bg-roxo border-r border-gray-200 sm:translate-x-0 dark:bg-roxo dark:border-gray-700" aria-label="Sidebar">
    <div class="h-full px-3 pb-4 overflow-y-auto bg-roxo dark:bg-roxo">
       <ul class="space-y-2 font-medium">
          <li>
             <a href="#" class="flex items-center p-2 text-gray-900 rounded-lg dark:text-white hover:bg-roxo dark:hover:bg-gray-700">
                <svg aria-hidden="true" class="w-6 h-6 text-gray-500 transition duration-75 dark:text-gray-400 group-hover:text-gray-900 dark:group-hover:text-white" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 20 20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M2 10a8 8 0 018-8v8h8a8 8 0 11-16 0z"></path><path d="M12 2.252A8.014 8.014 0 0117.748 8H12V2.252z"></path></svg>
                <span class="ml-3">Dashboard</span>
             </a>
          </li>
          <li>
             <a href="#" class="flex items-center p-2 text-gray-900 rounded-lg dark:text-white hover:bg-gray-100 dark:hover:bg-gray-700">
                <svg aria-hidden="true" class="flex-shrink-0 w-6 h-6 text-gray-500 transition duration-75 dark:text-gray-400 group-hover:text-gray-900 dark:group-hover:text-white" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 20 20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M5 3a2 2 0 00-2 2v2a2 2 0 002 2h2a2 2 0 002-2V5a2 2 0 00-2-2H5zM5 11a2 2 0 00-2 2v2a2 2 0 002 2h2a2 2 0 002-2v-2a2 2 0 00-2-2H5zM11 5a2 2 0 012-2h2a2 2 0 012 2v2a2 2 0 01-2 2h-2a2 2 0 01-2-2V5zM11 13a2 2 0 012-2h2a2 2 0 012 2v2a2 2 0 01-2 2h-2a2 2 0 01-2-2v-2z"></path></svg>
                <span class="flex-1 ml-3 whitespace-nowrap">Kanban</span>
                <span class="inline-flex items-center justify-center px-2 ml-3 text-sm font-medium text-gray-800 bg-gray-200 rounded-full dark:bg-gray-700 dark:text-gray-300">Pro</span>
             </a>
          </li>
          <li>
             <a href="#" class="flex items-center p-2 text-gray-900 rounded-lg dark:text-white hover:bg-gray-100 dark:hover:bg-gray-700">
                <svg aria-hidden="true" class="flex-shrink-0 w-6 h-6 text-gray-500 transition duration-75 dark:text-gray-400 group-hover:text-gray-900 dark:group-hover:text-white" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 20 20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M8.707 7.293a1 1 0 00-1.414 1.414l2 2a1 1 0 001.414 0l2-2a1 1 0 00-1.414-1.414L11 7.586V3a1 1 0 10-2 0v4.586l-.293-.293z"></path><path d="M3 5a2 2 0 012-2h1a1 1 0 010 2H5v7h2l1 2h4l1-2h2V5h-1a1 1 0 110-2h1a2 2 0 012 2v10a2 2 0 01-2 2H5a2 2 0 01-2-2V5z"></path></svg>
                <span class="flex-1 ml-3 whitespace-nowrap">Inbox</span>
                <span class="inline-flex items-center justify-center w-3 h-3 p-3 ml-3 text-sm font-medium text-blue-800 bg-blue-100 rounded-full dark:bg-blue-900 dark:text-blue-300">3</span>
             </a>
          </li>
          <li>
             <a href="#" class="flex items-center p-2 text-gray-900 rounded-lg dark:text-white hover:bg-gray-100 dark:hover:bg-gray-700">
                <svg aria-hidden="true" class="flex-shrink-0 w-6 h-6 text-gray-500 transition duration-75 dark:text-gray-400 group-hover:text-gray-900 dark:group-hover:text-white" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 20 20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M10 9a3 3 0 100-6 3 3 0 000 6zm-7 9a7 7 0 1114 0H3z" clip-rule="evenodd"></path></svg>
                <span class="flex-1 ml-3 whitespace-nowrap">Users</span>
             </a>
          </li>
          <li>
             <a href="#" class="flex items-center p-2 text-gray-900 rounded-lg dark:text-white hover:bg-gray-100 dark:hover:bg-gray-700">
                <svg aria-hidden="true" class="flex-shrink-0 w-6 h-6 text-gray-500 transition duration-75 dark:text-gray-400 group-hover:text-gray-900 dark:group-hover:text-white" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 20 20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M10 2a4 4 0 00-4 4v1H5a1 1 0 00-.994.89l-1 9A1 1 0 004 18h12a1 1 0 00.994-1.11l-1-9A1 1 0 0015 7h-1V6a4 4 0 00-4-4zm2 5V6a2 2 0 10-4 0v1h4zm-6 3a1 1 0 112 0 1 1 0 01-2 0zm7-1a1 1 0 100 2 1 1 0 000-2z" clip-rule="evenodd"></path></svg>
                <span class="flex-1 ml-3 whitespace-nowrap">Products</span>
             </a>
          </li>
          <li>
             <a href="#" class="flex items-center p-2 text-gray-900 rounded-lg dark:text-white hover:bg-gray-100 dark:hover:bg-gray-700">
                <svg aria-hidden="true" class="flex-shrink-0 w-6 h-6 text-gray-500 transition duration-75 dark:text-gray-400 group-hover:text-gray-900 dark:group-hover:text-white" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 20 20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M3 3a1 1 0 00-1 1v12a1 1 0 102 0V4a1 1 0 00-1-1zm10.293 9.293a1 1 0 001.414 1.414l3-3a1 1 0 000-1.414l-3-3a1 1 0 10-1.414 1.414L14.586 9H7a1 1 0 100 2h7.586l-1.293 1.293z" clip-rule="evenodd"></path></svg>
                <span class="flex-1 ml-3 whitespace-nowrap">Sign In</span>
             </a>
          </li>
          <li>
             <a href="#" class="flex items-center p-2 text-gray-900 rounded-lg dark:text-white hover:bg-gray-100 dark:hover:bg-gray-700">
                <svg aria-hidden="true" class="flex-shrink-0 w-6 h-6 text-gray-500 transition duration-75 dark:text-gray-400 group-hover:text-gray-900 dark:group-hover:text-white" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 20 20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M5 4a3 3 0 00-3 3v6a3 3 0 003 3h10a3 3 0 003-3V7a3 3 0 00-3-3H5zm-1 9v-1h5v2H5a1 1 0 01-1-1zm7 1h4a1 1 0 001-1v-1h-5v2zm0-4h5V8h-5v2zM9 8H4v2h5V8z" clip-rule="evenodd"></path></svg>
                <span class="flex-1 ml-3 whitespace-nowrap">Sign Up</span>
             </a>
          </li>
       </ul>
    </div>
 </aside>
```

**How the page is looking:**
[image]

**The Console:**
[image]

**About Failing to Load Flowbite.min.js:**
Because I'm using the Nestjs Framework, everything that is used by views and such need to be at the public folder, but I think it's unwise to remove a file from "node_module".

Any Tips on how I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

if you use flowbite-react you can change the background color of the sidebar as follows

```
const customTheme: CustomFlowbiteTheme['sidebar'] = {
    root: {
      base: 'bg-red-500',
      inner: 'bg-red-500'
    }
  } 


 <Sidebar
    theme={customTheme}
  >
    ......
  </Sidebar>
```